# Installing tensorflow on macos M1

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, apple-m1

I have a 2020 MacBook Air M1-chip with MacOS 12.2 Monterey. I have for the past several months tried pretty much everything to get tensorflow to work, but nothing seems to work. I tried with conda environments, tried installing tensorflow-deps, but I always got this error message:

```
(python_main) MacBook-Air-2:python_main martinwestin$ conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - tensorflow-deps

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/apple/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/apple/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

And if I pip install tensorflow and try to import it, I always get the error message:

```
Illegal instruction: 4
```

Does anyone have any ideas how this can be fixed, as I bought this computer for its advantages in training ML models...

Comment: I suggest doing a backup of your important data, wiping the machine to factory settings with a factory reset to avoid past failed installations interfering with the new one and then following an online tutorial (such as this one, as medium is usually a reputable source https://caffeinedev.medium.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-m1-mac-8e9b91d93706) step by step

Comment: You should follow the instructions here: https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

> this is maybe due to the fact that TensorFlow is not yet compatible
> with the Apple M1 chip. TensorFlow does not yet have official support
> for the M1 chip, and the current version of TensorFlow that is
> available for installation via pip is built for the x86 architecture

You can try installing tensorflow with pip but with the flag `pip install tensorflow --no-binary :all:`

> or you can use alternate method
>
> you can try using other libraries such as PyTorch or Jax that are
> compatible with M1 chip.

Comment: What is the source of the above quote? Because its incorrect, there is tensorflow-macos for M1/M2 support.

Comment: @dr.snoopy you can install using this command 'pip install tensorflow --no-binary :all:'

Comment: @jACOBAlex That is also incorrect, there is an official way which I linked in the question comments: https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/ Where do you get these incorrect commands?

Comment: i have search on google and some people solve this error by this command but if this is incorrect then i appologize